# No link to my edit in "Thanks for your edit!" message on tag wiki

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

So I went and edited [cpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpan) or https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cpan/info and got the thank you message:

> Thanks for your edit!
>
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

But "peer reviewed." wasn't a link to [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8300602) like when I edit a question.

It's the same message and I was expecting a link :)